# Is there any way to access .cmd file path in command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a .cmd a file and I want to write some code in it. But first of all I want a code to open the .cmd file path and **when someone clicks my .cmd file, it's dir opens in command prompt**. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: Either begin the batch file with ```@CD /D "%~dp0"```, or ```@PushD "%~dp0"```

Answer (score 0):

fixed
Just copy this code in your .cmd file:

```
cd /d %~dp0
call cmd
```

Comment: `cd /d %~dp0` does not work on batch file is stored, for example, in the directory `C:\Temp\Development & Test(!)_100%`. Yes, that is an awful directory name, but a valid directory name. I have seen every possible character in user account names and so in often used directory paths. The first command line does also not work on file being stored on a network resource and executed by using its UNC path, for example `\\Server\Share\Batch Folder\BatchFile.cmd` because of `cmd.exe` denies by default setting a UNC path as current directory.

Comment: Please run in a command prompt window also `call /?` and read the output usage help which explains `%~dp0` (drive and path of argument 0 which is the full path of the directory containing the currently processed batch file) and explains in short description also that the command `call` is for calling a batch file from within a batch file or run command lines below a label like a subroutine in a new batch file context. It is not needed for running an executable like `cmd.exe` specified in your second command line just with its file name `cmd` instead of its fully qualified file name `%ComSpec%`

Comment: Hint: Use a www search engine with searching for `Windows Explorer open command prompt here` and look on the found pages. You will find out that your batch file is not needed at all for the purpose you most likely want to achieve, open a command prompt window with current directory being the folder currently selected in Windows File Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

What's mean 'dir opens in command prompt'? If you want to o**pen new cmd window from current dir**, just add to your file the following command:

```
start cmd
```

Or even

```
start cmd @cmd /k dir
```

if you want to **see a content of the current directory in that window**. Also you can **open the current folder in Windows Explorer** - just add to your file this command:

```
explorer .
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but it opens two cmd tabs. I think it's better to use "cd /d %~dp0"